# Como buscar um elemento com a mesma classe dependendo da quantidade de filhos?

Tags: javascript, jquery

O meu cenário é o seguinte, eu tenho duas `ul` com `li`. As `uls` possuem a mesma classe, porém eu queria manipular apenas uma delas, no caso, a que possui apenas uma `li` como filha.

Exemplo:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMXpVg

Exemplo 2:

```
 <ul class="teste">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="teste">
<li>1</li>
</ul>
```

Eu preciso manipular apenas a `ul` teste que **tenha apenas 1 filho**, que no caso é a segunda.

Pensei em selecionar todas as `uls`, e fazer uma verificação com o `childElementCount`, se fosse maior que `1`, eu aplicaria um CSS na `ul`, se não, nada aconteceria. Porém tentei usar o próprio `childElementCount` e não consegui fazer a comparação, tentei o `.find()` também.

Comment: Nao entendi o que você quer fazer.

Comment: [Olhe isso](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

Comment: @PauloHDSousa, veja se entende agora

Answer (score 3, accepted):

você pode procurar pela li pertencente a `.teste` que é filha unica, então acessar o parentNode da mesma.

```js
var itens = document.querySelectorAll(".teste li:only-child");
var listas =[].map.call(itens, function (item, indice) {
  return item.parentNode;
})
console.log(listas);
```

```html
<ul class="teste">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="teste">
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

caso prefira, em jQuery:

```js
var listas = $(".teste li:only-child").parent();
console.log(listas);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="teste">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="teste">
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, só achei a utilização do Jquery.filter mais simples pro meu entendimento.

Comment: @haykou pode ficar ainda mais simples utilizando o exemplo do TobyMosque `var $minhaUl = $(".teste li:only-child").parent();`

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior tinha esqueci que o `.parent()` faz exatamente a mesma coisa que o meu `.map` estava fazendo.

Comment: valeu galera, nao sei nem qual marcar como resposta porque todas funcionaram

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira é utilizando o [jQuery.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```js
var $elementos = $(".teste");

var $minhaUl = $elementos.filter(function() {
  return $(this).find('li').length === 1;
});

$minhaUl.css('background', 'blue');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="teste">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="teste">
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Peguei segue seu código js e adicionei o if que você precisa.

```
var lista = document.querySelectorAll('.lista');
console.log(lista);
var listaj = $('.lista');
console.log(listaj.size());
$( ".lista" ).each(function( index ) {
 if( $(this).find("li").length == 1)
   //Código aqui apenas 1 item na LI.
});
```

Comment: método .size ()  é obsoleto a partir do jQuery 1.8.

Comment: @durtto ele fez assim no código dele, só adaptei a parte final

Answer (score -2):

Tente isso, colocar uma id na sua `ul`.

```
<ul id="minhaLista">
    <li>Elemento 1</li>
    <li>Elemento 2</li>
</ul>
```

Para saber o tamanho:

> $("#minhaLista li").length